# ListPlot is not plotting functions from DSolve, brought by ReplaceAll(/.) command

Tags: plotting, manipulate, animation

I have the following simple differential equation

```
ODE = DSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 1}, x[t], t]
```

and I'd like to visualize how the solution `x[t]` behaves over time in space (which is just along the x-axis), so I tried the following

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[{{x[t] /. ODE, 0}},PlotRange->{{0,10},{-1,1}}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

but this gives blank output. Oddly the simple `Plot` command outputs expected result. I assume that the nature of these two commands is inherently different, or `Manipulate` is screwing something here. What would be the reason/would there be any word-around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the way the replacements are made. `ODE` is a replacement rule that looks like:

```
{{x[t] -> 1 + t}}
```

The `Manipulate` effectively tries to evaluate something like the following (for some value of `t` you selected):

```
DynamicModule[{t = 10}, ListPlot[{{x[t] /. ODE, 0}}]]
```

The problem here is that during the evaluation, `x[t]` first gets evaluated to `x[10]` and then the replacement rule `x[t] -> 1 + t` doesn't match `x[10]` any more.

You can fix this in two ways. The first way is to use this definition of `ODE` instead:

```
ODE = First @ DSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 1}, x, t]
Manipulate[ListPlot[{{x[t] /. ODE, 0}}, PlotRange -> {{0,10},{-1,1}}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

> {x -> Function[{t}, 1 + t]}

This works because the replacement rule now specifies that `x` is a function, rather than that `x[t]` is a symbolic expression.

The second (and in my opinion the superior) way is to use `DSolveValue` instead so you don't have to muck about with replacement rules at all:

```
ODE = DSolveValue[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 1}, x, t]
Manipulate[ListPlot[{{ODE[t], 0}}, PlotRange -> {{0,10},{-1,1}}], {t, 0, 30}]
```

> Function[{t}, 1 + t]

## Edit

You also remarked that `Plot` does work. This is because `Plot` uses `Block` to assign a value to `t` and in that case the value of `t` in `x[t]` and in `ODE` matches again. Compare:

```
Block[{t = 10}, x[t] /. ODE]
Module[{t = 10}, x[t] /. ODE]
```

Comment: This clarified the problem I was having and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you want but...

```
ODE = DSolve[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 1}, x[t], t]

Manipulate[
 Plot[x[t] /. ODE // Evaluate, {t, 0, T}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}], {T, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, `Plot` works fine. But `ListPlot` doesn't work correctly with `Manipulate`. I want to see how the coordinate of `x[t]` moves in space over time. So my first approach was to plot the coordinate `{x[t],0}` along the x-axis and manipulate/animate time, which doesn't seem to work so simply.